# "No tests were found" after Proguard test APK

Tags: android, unit-testing, proguard

I've come across a strange problem after enabling Proguard on my testing APK.  Proguard is enabled on both the testing and tested apps.
I'm using Android Studio 1.2.11 and Gradle 1.2.3

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildTypes {
    // Development configuration.
    debug {
        debuggable true
        jniDebuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        // Configure ProGuard
        minifyEnabled true

        // Default configuration
        proguardFile 'proguard/proguard.cfg'

        // Add all of our component-specific configurations (excluding the Android generic, as we want it to be last)
        FileTree tree =  fileTree(dir: 'proguard', include: '*.txt', exclude: 'Android.txt')
        tree.each {File file ->
            proguardFile file.getCanonicalPath()
        }

        // Android fallbacks
        proguardFile 'proguard/Android.txt'

        // Debug configuration
        proguardFile 'proguard/proguard-debug.cfg'

        // Test configuration
        testProguardFile 'proguard/proguard-test.cfg'
    }
}
```

Here is proguard.cfg:

```
# Defaults from ProGuard
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Turn off optimization (as it can cause plenty of headaches)
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
```

proguard-debug.cfg (very simple):

```
# Turn off obfuscation
-dontobfuscate
```

And finally proguard-test.cfg (also very simple):

```
# Turn off obfuscation
-dontobfuscate

# Unit tests
-dontwarn sun.reflect.**
-dontwarn org.junit.**
-dontwarn org.mockito.**
-dontwarn org.apache.tools.ant.**
```

The other Proguard configs are for various plugins we use and really should not make a difference.  I can post them if you're interested.

The build of both the testing and tested app APKs work fine. But when the testing APK is installed and runs, I get "No tests were found".
I've verified that if I run the test on a non-Proguard buildType, the tests run fine.

Additionally, I've examined `seeds.txt` and `dump.txt` from the Proguard output, and have verified that the testing code is indeed present in the testing APK.
Furthermore, there is no `usage.txt` (the file that lists code stripped from the APK) which implies that my test code was not removed by Proguard.  There is also no mapping.txt file because I set `-dontobfuscate` in `proguard-test.cfg`.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So, I noticed from logcat that the errors are due to certain ClassNotFoundExceptions. For instance:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.okhttp2.ResponseBuilderExtension" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/wp.wpbeta.test-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/wp.wpbeta-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/wp.wpbeta-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

This is very strange because these classes should be preserved by our Proguard config. In fact, if I check `dump.txt`, I see that it is present:

```
+ Program class: com/newrelic/agent/android/instrumentation/okhttp2/ResponseBuilderExtension
  Superclass:    com/squareup/okhttp/Response$Builder
  Major version: 0x32
  Minor version: 0x0
    = target 1.6
  Access flags:  0x21
    = public class com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.okhttp2.ResponseBuilderExtension extends com.squareup.okhttp.Response$Builder
```

Comment: You have a lot of proguard files. See if just one of them causes the problem alone and then post it's content.

Comment: Thanks @weston, I've added proguard*.cfg files. The other Proguard configs are specific to a couple plugins and I don't think they are the cause of the problem. For brevity's sake I didn't post them here.

Answer (score 3):

Proguard and NewRelic don't always play nice without specific exceptions made for NR.
Make sure these are in your relevant proguard config.

```
-keep class com.newrelic.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**
-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses
```